# How to strip output of grep?

Tags: linux, grep, strip, linux-disk-free

I'm writing a script which utilises the salt-cli (SaltStack) as well as generic command line arguments to produce a simple HTML-based table outlining all of our servers' Hardware specs and software versions.

It's as simple as it sounds, however my only challenge is stripping my commands outputs so that they can be presented nicely in a table (e.g. one word/number rather than the whole output).

My latest challenge that I'm yet to strip effectively is the output of a simple 'df -Ph. So far I have got it down to this:

```
'df -Ph /'
```

My output:

```
 Filesystem                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vhfhuffu               50G  8.0G   39G  18% /
```

I would like it to only show the available for each server, I can't find a reliable way to do this for ever Unix server.

Comment: What's exactly the question? Just extract `39G` in above example of sum up possible different filesystems? And how is this related to grep?

Comment: Because I need to find a way of finding the sum of 'Avail' for every machine, I am running this command across 15 servers. @SergeBallesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with this due to my need to run this command from a script via Salt which requires '' around the cmd.run

df -Ph / | grep / | awk '"'"'{ print $4}'"'"''

Ugly but it's the only thing that works in such a niche case

Answer (score 0):

`tail` and `cut` should be enough here:

```
 df -Ph / | tail +2 | cut -f4 -w
```

should give you the file system size of the root file system.

Comment: @jto: My bad. I forgot to control the actual Linux man page, and -P option is different on my BSD system...

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way is to combine `tail -n 1` to get the last line and pass it through `grep '{print $4}'. This will extract the`39G` value that it sounds like you want, e.g.

```
$ df -Ph / | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'
39G
```

If it is some other number you are trying to *sum*, just let me know.

Comment: I ended up using something similar to this method:  df -Ph / | grep / | awk '{ print $4}', I'm just struggling to physically run this command now as I have to run it via the salt-cli i.e,  salt '*' cmd.run 'df -Ph / | grep / | awk '{ print $4}'', it doesn't like the fact the print command ends in ' as well as the salt-cli syntax, how can I get around this? @David C. Rankin

Comment: I was curious. This is the first I've ever hear of a `salt-cli`. Is it some new shell I haven't heard of, or is it more like a PowerShell windows thing?

Comment: It is a remote execution and configuration management tool which has a command line feature much like aws-cli

Comment: The syntax is as follows: salt '<targetmachine>' cmd.run '<command>' my problem is that my command uses ' ' along with the salt-cli syntax, so it doesn't like it and throws as error

Comment: Have you tried escaping the quote (but that may give `awk` heartburn. I'd google a bit and see if there is anything salt specific related to quoting that pops up.

Comment: I've tried but to no avail, there isn't much out there about Salt minus their own documentation

Comment: I'll try digging -- I'm interested in what salt is. But that will be in the morning... I'm squinting at the keyboard as it is now `:p`

Comment: I found a solution, you led my down the right route with the escaping comment! I had to do it the ugly way (e.g. '"'"'{ print $4}'"'"'')

Answer (score 0):

You are able to extract the needed column value using `--output` option:

```
df -h --output=avail | tail -n +2
```